# AvaloniaLocator Current does not exists Linux

Tags: image, assets, avaloniaui, avalonia

AvaloniaLocator.Current is not a public property and in the docs that I read they all use it. So im trying to update an image if it is a folder or file but I read that you have to convert it yourself so i did this

```cs
var assets = AvaloniaLocator.Current.GetService<IAssetLoader>();
var asset = assets.Open(uri);
```

but apparently AvaloniaLocator.Current is internal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I shortly figured it out after a bit more digging you will have to replace `var assets = AvaloniaLocator.Current.GetService<IAssetLoader>();` with the new class `AssetLoader`, it is explained better in https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Avalonia-11-Porting-Guide

Comment: If you've found the answer to your own question, it helps to mark this as the accepted answer so others can quickly identify this question has been answered.